# Align equations with equivalent and equal sign

Tags: align

I am currently trying to get the align environment to work as I want it to work.

```
\begin{align}
&& a \cdot c + b &= 0\\
\Leftrightarrow && a \cdot c &= -b\\
\end{align}
```

This code will align the equivalent sign in the middle of the left half and the equal sign in the middle of the right half. What I actually want is that the equivalent sign is on the outer left of the page and the formula is in the middle of the remaining page. How can this be done and is this even encouraged? Or is there a better way to align formula with equivalent and equal signs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  a \cdot c + b &= 0 \\
  \Leftrightarrow \qquad a \cdot c &= -b
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  a \cdot c + b &= 0 \\
  \llap{$\Leftrightarrow$ \qquad} a \cdot c &= -b
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  a \cdot c + b &= 0 \\
  a \cdot c &= -b \refstepcounter{equation}\tag*{(\theequation)\llap{\makebox[\linewidth][l]{$\Leftrightarrow$}}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The first sets the `\Leftrightarrow` a distance of `\qquad` from the second equation. The second does the same, but removes any influence of `\Leftrightarrow` in terms of the horizontal spacing. The third sets it as part of the `\tag*` in order to position it on the left of the text block boundary.

<sub>The text block boundary is obtained by using the [`showframe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe); not included in the above MWE.</sub>

Comment: I like both, thx!

Comment: The first two are ambiguous, the third is abominable. `;-)`

Comment: While the first two works in this particular case, the solution is limited because it will get hard to align a third line of equivalence. Maybe better to use the `alignat` environment.

Answer (score 5):

The first construction I propose below is sometimes used in a blackboard; for a written document, I'd suggest using the natural language and `\shortintertext` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a \cdot c + b &= 0 \\
&\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\Leftrightarrow$} \notag \\ 
a \cdot c &= -b
\end{align}

\begin{align}
a \cdot c + b &= 0 \\
\shortintertext{if and only if}
a \cdot c &= -b
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Definitly options if theres only 2 or 3 formula.

Comment: @Kamairo it's nor to demerit Werner's answer (he gives what you asked for), but take into account that in all my years as a mathematician I've never ever seen that way to represent the equivalence between two expressions, specially the one with the sign flushed to the margin.

Comment: Or precede the equations by “the two following equations are equivalent”; I agree with the idea of avoiding symbols.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use either the `aligned` environment or the `alignat` environment as they also work for **more than two lines**.

As the `aligned` environment can only be used within a an `equation` environment, you will not be able to label lines separately. In this case, you must use the `alignat` environment. Also, note the `\quad` when using `alignat`, which is necessary for good looking spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
                        && a \cdot c + b    &= 0 \\
        \Leftrightarrow && a \cdot c        &= -b \\
        \Leftrightarrow && a                &= -\frac{b}{c}
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}

    \begin{alignat}{2}
                        \quad&& a \cdot c + b    &= 0 \\
        \Leftrightarrow \quad&& a \cdot c        &= -b \\
        \Leftrightarrow \quad&& a                &= -\frac{b}{c}
    \end{alignat} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image: example]