# Float equals sign left in equation

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath

Trying to have an equals sign flush left with the margin, while centring the rest of the equation, found the best solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191095/align-equations-with-equivalent-and-equal-sign), but it seems like there would be a better way to do it, given that the symbol is in the same place every time.

The solution I have:

```
\begin{align*}
(s + 6.72 + 9.95 j)(s + 6.72 - 9.95 j) \refstepcounter{equation}\tag*{\llap{\makebox[\linewidth][l]{$=$}}}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you mean *flush right* with the (right) margin or *flushleft* with the (left) margin?

Comment: it would be easier if you posted a full small document. In particular are your equation numbers on the left or right, here you seem to step the equation number but don't print it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to achieve what you're after, using `flalign`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\insertmath}{\rule{5em}{.5\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
    && f(x) = \insertmath && \\
  = && (\insertmath)(\insertmath)
\end{flalign*}

\begin{flalign*}
    && & f(x) = \insertmath & \\
  = && & (\insertmath)(\insertmath)
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```