# Align equivalence arrows and equal signs without weird spacing

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

I want to achieve the following layout:

```
    1a = 1b
<=> 2a = 2b
<=> 3a = 3b
```

I.e., I want the `\Leftrightarrow`s and the `=`signs to be aligned.
Here's what I thought would do the trick:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
                   & 1a &= 1b  \\
    \Leftrightarrow&  2a &= 2b  \\
    \Leftrightarrow&  3a &= 3b.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The spacing is clearly off.
If I add another align indicator, I get the following result:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
    &               & 1a &= 1b  \\
    &\Leftrightarrow&  2a &= 2b \\
    &\Leftrightarrow&  3a &= 3b.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This looks better. But how do I get rid of the extra spacing between the arrows and the variables?
A [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191095/align-equations-with-equivalent-and-equal-sign) couldn't really help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've discovered experimentally that `n` alignment points require `2n – 1` ampersands (n for the alignment points, and n – 1 to introduce each new alignment column)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the internal form `aligned`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Thus,
\[
\begin{aligned}
    &               &  1a &= 1b  \\
    &\Leftrightarrow&  2a &= 2b \\
    &\Leftrightarrow&  3a &= 3b.
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to control the spacing, `alignedat` is your friend

```
\[
\begin{alignedat}{2}
    &               & \quad 1a &= 1b  \\
    &\Leftrightarrow&  2a &= 2b \\
    &\Leftrightarrow&  3a &= 3b.
\end{alignedat}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\begin{alignedat}{2}
    &               & \qquad 1a &= 1b  \\
    &\Leftrightarrow&  2a &= 2b \\
    &\Leftrightarrow&  3a &= 3b.
\end{alignedat}
\]
```

[image]

Use `\quad` or `\qquad` or whatever spacing command introduces the amount of space you desire.

Comment: Thank you. The first approach already solved the problem in this case.

Answer (score 4):

In this case I would just use `\iff` instead of `\Leftrightarrow`, since `\iff` adds the proper spacing on both sides of the arrow and with form of the expression it is already aligned. In general you could use `alignat*` instead of `align*` to adjust the spacing between the arrows and the equalities as you wish.

Here's an example for both cases.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
With \verb|\iff|:
\begin{align*}
         1a &= 1b  \\
    \iff 2a &= 2b \\
    \iff 3a &= 3b.
\end{align*}
With \verb|alignat*|:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    &\qquad         & 1a &= 1b  \\
    &\Leftrightarrow& 2a &= 2b \\
    &\Leftrightarrow& 3a &= 3b.
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While it's surely true that `\iff` adds some space (+1) the alignment is here a happy coincidence which won't in general present itself.

Comment: @campa Thanks for pointing it out, I should indeed have mentioned it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!